# Iframe disappears/does not append when nearby element is set

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the following schema

```
<div id="test">
</div>
```

and code to append iframe:

```
var element = document.getElementById("test");

var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.className = "some_iframe";
    iframe.style.position = "relative";
    iframe.style.webkitTransform = 'scale(1)';
    iframe.style.zIndex = 20;
    iframe.src = "some_src";
    element.appendChild(iframe);
```

**The code appends to the div with id "test" just fine**. Now here's the strange part.

If my schema is like this:

```
<div style = "position:absolute;" id="another_div">
     Some random text
</div>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

The iframe does not append anymore. **And if I had the iframe appended** and manually manipulate the html to append "Some random text" as in the example above (inside the div) **the iframe dissapears**. Any idea on this one? Never faced someething so ghastly before...

Comment: Does your code run after the DOM is ready, or at least after the `div` has been rendered? If not, that's your issue.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld After the div has been rendered...

Comment: Consider reproducing the problem on http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @Vohuman already did https://jsfiddle.net/u5ofg9j6/1/  it would be something like this but I'm getting "appendIframe is not defined" (I'm not really an expert with jsfiddle, I don't know I need to include the javascript or something)... Alternating the removal of "ete" should allow the append of the iframe or not at all...

Comment: Use the `no wrap - *` option from the second drop down menu in the left panel.